# Moving files to a different folder, ignore the existing files

Tags: command-line, bash, files, mv

I want to move all the files from parent folder to child folder... and ignore the existing files in the child folder, i.e. if `img1.jpg` exists in both parent and child folder, it should not be replaced in child folder.

I can move the files like below:

```
mv ./parent/*.jpg ./parent/child/
```

but don't know how to tell Ubuntu to ignore the existing files?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Per the mv man page, the '-n' flag will not overwrite existing files:

```
-n, --no-clobber
          do not overwrite an existing file
```

Comment: so I should use: `mv -n ./parent/*.jpg ./parent/child/` ?

Comment: Executing the command you indicated will result in all files ending in .jpg being moved to the ./parent/child/ path, without overwriting files with the same name in the destination.